# How to compare value of one row with all the other rows in PySpark on grouped values

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

### Problem statement

Consider the following data (see code generation at the bottom)

```
+-----+-----+-------+--------+
|index|group|low_num|high_num|
+-----+-----+-------+--------+
|    0|    1|      1|       1|
|    1|    1|      2|       2|
|    2|    1|      3|       3|
|    3|    2|      1|       3|
+-----+-----+-------+--------+
```

Then for a given index, I want to count how many times that one indexes `high_num` is greater than `low_num` for all `low_num` in the `group`.

For instance, consider the second row with `index`: `1`. `Index`: `1` is in `group`: `1` and the `high_num` is `2`. `high_num` on index `1` is greater than the `high_num` on index `0`, equal to `low_num`, and smaller than the one on index `2`. So the `high_num` of `index`: 1 is greater than  `low_num` across the group once, so then I want the value in the answer column to say `1`.

#### Dataset with desired output

```
+-----+-----+-------+--------+-------+
|index|group|low_num|high_num|desired|
+-----+-----+-------+--------+-------+
|    0|    1|      1|       1|      0|
|    1|    1|      2|       2|      1|
|    2|    1|      3|       3|      2|
|    3|    2|      1|       3|      1|
+-----+-----+-------+--------+-------+
```

### Dataset generation code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .getOrCreate()
)
## Example df
## Note the inclusion of "desired" which is the desired output.
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
        (1, 1, 2, 2, 1),
        (2, 1, 3, 3, 2),
        (3, 2, 1, 3, 1)
    ],
    schema=["index", "group", "low_num", "high_num", "desired"]
)
```

### Pseudocode that might have solved the problem

A pseusocode might look like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w_spec = Window.partitionBy("group").rowsBetween(
    Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

## F.collect_list_when does not exist
## F.current_col does not exist
## Probably wouldn't work like this anyways
ddf = df.withColumn("Counts", 
                    F.size(F.collect_list_when(
                             F.current_col("high_number") > F.col("low_number"), 1
                          ).otherwise(None).over(w_spec))
                   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `filter` on the `collect_list`, and check its `size`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'desired', 
    F.expr('size(filter(collect_list(low_num) over (partition by group), x -> x < high_num))')
)

df2.show()
+-----+-----+-------+--------+-------+
|index|group|low_num|high_num|desired|
+-----+-----+-------+--------+-------+
|    0|    1|      1|       1|      0|
|    1|    1|      2|       2|      1|
|    2|    1|      3|       3|      2|
|    3|    2|      1|       3|      1|
+-----+-----+-------+--------+-------+
```